# SAS - How to get last 'n' observations from a dataset?

Tags: sas, dataset

How can you create a SAS data set from another dataset using only the last n observations from original dataset. This is easy when you know the value of n. If I don't know 'n' how can this be done?

Comment: What do you mean you don't know 'n'?  How are you going to find out the value of 'n' - is it a dataset variable, a macro variable, a parameter?

Answer (score 8):

This assumes you have a macro variable that says how many observations you want.  NOBS tells you the number of observations in the dataset currently without reading the whole thing.

```
%let obswant=5;
data want;
set sashelp.class nobs=obscount;
if _n_ gt (obscount-&obswant.);
run;
```

Answer (score 4):

Using Joe's example of a macro variable to specify the number of observations you want, here is another answer:

```
%let obswant = 10;
data want;
   do _i_=nobs-(&obswant-1) to nobs;
      set have point=_i_ nobs=nobs;
      output;
      end;
   stop;  /* Needed to stop data step */
run;
```

This should perform better since it only reads the specific observations you want.

Comment: I'm curious about the conditions for "this should perform better".  I suspect it's some of each; random access is not as fast as sequential access, so there is some loss there.  May test it out if I have some time.  I suspect if you are using most of the observations that it will be faster to do it sequentially, but if it is a large dataset and you want a small number of observations it is faster to do it random=access.  Makes me wish SAS had a way to open a dataset in reverse order without having to sort it first.

Comment: @Joe Imagine a dataset with 1 million obs and you want the "last" 10.  Using this technique, only 10 "input" operations are performed.  Using just the NOBS value requires 1 million "input" operations.  Depending on how "wide" the data set is, this difference can be very significant.

Comment: Right, I certainly see the possibility for this being faster.  I am curious at which point it is faster/slower (ie, what size of dataset, what % of data being pulled - 10 from 1MM of course would be faster, but what about 500k from 1MM?)

Answer (score 4):

If the dataset is large, you might not want to read the whole dataset. Instead you could try a construction that reads the total number of Observations in the dataset first. So if you want to have the last  of observations:

```
data t;
  input x;
datalines;
1
2
3
4
;

%let dsid=%sysfunc(open(t));
%let num=%sysfunc(attrn(&dsid,nlobs));
%let rc=%sysfunc(close(&dsid));
%let number = 2;

data tt;
set t (firstobs =  %eval(&num.-&number.+1));
run;
```

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of variety, here's another approach (not necessarily a better one)

```
%let obswant=5;

proc sql noprint;
select nlobs-&obswant.+1 into :obscalc
from dictionary.tables
where libname='SASHELP' and upcase(memname)='CLASS';
quit;

data want;
set sashelp.class (firstobs=&obscalc.);
run;
```

Comment: Note: you want to specify format when using select..into, otherwise the value is formatted as BEST8., which leads to weird bugs when you select a value >= 100,000,000 (it's formatted in exponential notation, leading to rounding).

Answer (score 0):

You can achive this using the
`_nobs_` and `_n_` variables. First, create a temporary variable to store the total no of obs. Then compare the automatic variable *N* to *nobs*.

```
data a;
set sashelp.class nobs=_nobs_;
if _N_ gt _nobs_ -5;
run;
```